# Why my material seems weird?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv

[image]

I'm trying to create a studio on blender.When i apply a material to object, upper side of the plane (which i extruded on edit mode and than added bevel.) texture seems repeating and broken.How can i fix this?

Comment: because you've extruded so the topology of your object has changed, you need to unwrap again

Comment: Just go to edit mode and select all with "A" key and hit "U" key for unwrapping options and then just choose any of the options which best suits your need, "smart UV project" option can be preferred.